# Is there a way to attach my console to a heroku app as to see the app/website activity?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I'm using heroku to deplay a node.js website with my Mac (Mac OS 10.6.8. Snow Leopard). I have node 0.6.8.

Is there a way to see the watch the app's activity, for example console.log information?

"heroku console" and "heroku run console" don't seem to work...

Thanks!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You have three options. From best to worst, they are:

1. Use `heroku logs` or `heroku logs --tail` to see what your Node process is writing to the console. For more information, see [the documentation for `heroku logs`](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging).
2. Use `heroku run node` to run your Node app interactively. The only problem with this is that your app will start when you execute the run command, and it will exit when you exit. You can read more about this in [the Heroku documentation for Node](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-js#console)
3. Redirect the process's `stdout` and `stderr` to a file, which you can watch for activity. A code example of how to do this is available at http://pastebin.com/tpNvgv2a.